# How to read a text file into a 3D or 4 D array in bash/shell scripting and then read each element individually

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, matrix, dimension

Is there a way to read a text file into a 3D or 4 D array in bash/shell scripting and then read each element individually
Input file :

```
A1 10 20.1 2
P1 20 30.1 3 
K1 30 50.2 4
```

and then be able to read something like this:

```
Arr (0,0) = A1
Arr (0,3) = 2
Arr (2,2) = 50.2
```

I tried this but not what I have expected.

```
declare -A arr  
declare -i c=0

while read -r M1 M2 M3 M4; do
    arr[$c,0]="$M1"; arr[$c,1]="$M2"; arr[$c,2]="$M3"; arr[$c,3]="$M4"
    c=c+1
done < ip1

for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]}/2;i++)); do
    echo "${arr[$i,0]} ${arr[$i,1]} ${arr[$i,2]} ${arr[$i,3]}"
done
```

Comment: Bash does not have multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: If you create a non-XY question with a [mcve] we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do.